# How can I find out the build number I just built in Jenkins with REST API?

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins, I remotely build with REST API like below.

curl -X POST 'http://@{IP}:{PORT}/job/subjob/buildWithParameters?token=????

But, it does not return build number.

lastBuild cannot guarantee the build number I really triggered because some others can trigger remotely.

Is there any method to get the build number I just triggered in Jenkins with REST API?

Answer (score 0):

After you triggered the job, it will be either in queue or has been started. If the job is queued you can `GET`

```
JENKINS_URL:8080/queue/item/QUEUE_NUMBER/api/json?pretty=true
```

to return  information about that queue item. Because depending on the load of your Jenkins server, the item that was queued may or may not be run immediately. If it runs immediately, by running the GET request above you could get the BUILD_NUMBER. If a build job has not yet started, this information will be blank.